# coerce a data.frame with different columns, with another data.frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two data frames with unequal column dimensions that I am trying to add together. I am open to other possible solutions, but ideally, I would like to coerce the data frame with a lesser amount of columns to be the same size as the other data frame and introduce NA's where the data is missing. Here's some code:

```
sampleDF1 <- data.frame(v1 = c(1,1,1), v2 = c(1,1,1), v3 = c(1,1,1))
sampleDF2 <- data.frame(v1 = c(1,1,1), v2 = c(1,1,1))

desiredOutput <- data.frame(v1 = c(1,1,1), v2 = c(1,1,1), v3 = c(NA,NA,NA))

# Final operation that I want to compute
sampleDF1 + desiredOutput
```

Thank you for all your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that both dataframes have the same number of rows and you only need to add columns to `sampleDF2` (and not add columns to both), this will work for you:

```
sampleDF2[,names(sampleDF1)[!names(sampleDF1) %in% names(sampleDF2)]] <- NA
sampleDF2
##   v1 v2 v3
## 1  1  1 NA
## 2  1  1 NA
## 3  1  1 NA
all.equal(sampleDF2, desiredOutput)
## [1] TRUE
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! I'll mark this as my solution in a couple of hours, as I'm curious what others come up with. Thanks Thomas!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more simple and readable version of @Thomas' answer using `setdiff`:

```
> sampleDF2[, setdiff( names(sampleDF1), names(sampleDF2) ) ] <- NA
> sampleDF2
  v1 v2 v3
1  1  1 NA
2  1  1 NA
3  1  1 NA
```